# Who "inherits" a private corporation if all documented owners have died?

Tags: insurance

This is totally hypothetical, but I'm looking for a real answer.

Let's say five friends and I file articles of incorporation for a small tech start-up. The six of us are the board of directors. Let's also say that our small tech start-up does exceptionally well. So well, in fact, that we are able to build our own office building (moving out of our parents' garage) and hire support staff. We're conscientious business owners, so we purchase all generous insurance policies for our business. In the event of disaster, we should be able to pick up and move and carry on with business with only minor hiccups.

Now, let's say there's a fire in our new building. For argument's sake, let's say that the cause of the fire is such that our generous insurance would be responsible (and not the liability insurance of some contractor, or some natural disaster where no insurance would cover us). Unfortunately, all six of us were in the building at the time of the fire and we perished, along with all the work our corporation was doing.

For all intents and purposes, the corporation (as an entity) had "died." (The six members on the articles of incorporation are dead and all the work they created had been destroyed.)

If the insurance company was going to pay out ... who would collect? It's my understanding that all legal parties associated with the corporation are deceased, so there wouldn't be anyone on any legal document capable of filing a claim or collecting said insurance. Would any of the original founders' next-of-kin be responsible for this, or, is the corporation, in fact, dead?

Comment: This question seems better suited for [law.se].  Either way, you need to specify a jurisdiction: country and probably also state.

Comment: All documented owners have heirs, who automatically become owners. In an extreme case where no heirs can be found, the state can become the owner.

Comment: You're dead so it's not your concern

Answer (score 5):

(I am not a lawyer)

Your corporation won’t end with the lives of the people who created it. That’s one of the fundamental principles of incorporation. Your articles of incorporation may include rules about succession planning that could (should) cover ownership scenarios, within the laws of your locality pertaining to corporations. Also, depending on your locality, your share of the company is part of what you own, and becomes part of your estate upon your death. Local laws will dictate who inherits your estate, and how. If your hypothetical situation is based in reality for you, you should consult a good lawyer (who knows both business law and estate law).

Life insurance payouts go to whomever is named as the beneficiary of the policy. If the beneficiary is deceased or no longer exists (a corporation or trust can be named as a beneficiary), then the insurance payout goes to a contingent beneficiary, if one is designated on the policy. If all of the beneficiaries are deceased then your local estate laws will govern who receives the insurance payout.

The Workplace principle here is that business ownership can be very complex and you need to pay a qualified legal professional to help you get it right.